# MSProject show main resource on Summary tasks

Tags: ms-project, resource-planning, tasks, ms-project-2013

How can I show the main (resource with maximum hours) for Summary tasks.
I suspect I would need to set a custom text field to show this, but how would I structure this?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below function does what I was after.

```
Public Sub showMainResource()

    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    Dim tsk As Task
    Dim rsc As Resource
    Dim ass As Assignment

    Dim dataArr() As Double
    Dim dataArrCount As Long
    dataArrCount = -1

    Dim resourceCount As Long
    resourceCount = ActiveProject.Resources.Count

    Dim taskCount As Long
    taskCount = ActiveProject.Tasks.Count

    ReDim dataArr(taskCount, resourceCount)

    Dim iMax As Long
    Dim iID As Long

    'walk the tasks backwards
    For i = taskCount To 1 Step -1
        Set tsk = ActiveProject.Tasks.Item(i)

        'loop through resource assignments and add hours
        For Each ass In tsk.Assignments
            'log the value
            dataArr(tsk.ID, ass.Resource.ID) = dataArr(tsk.ID, ass.Resource.ID) + ass.Work
        Next ass

        'add the values to the parent
        For j = 1 To resourceCount
            'log the value to its parent as well
            dataArr(tsk.OutlineParent.ID, j) = dataArr(tsk.OutlineParent.ID, j) + dataArr(tsk.ID, j)
        Next j

        'code to do something with the results,
        'below takes the resource with highest work and shows it in Text2 for Summary tasks only
        If tsk.Summary Then
            iMax = 0
            iID = 0
            For j = 1 To resourceCount
                'find the reource with max work
                If dataArr(tsk.ID, j) > iMax Then
                    iMax = dataArr(tsk.ID, j)
                    iID = j
                End If
            Next j
            If iID > 0 Then
                'write the value
                tsk.Text2 = ActiveProject.Resources.Item(iID).Name
            Else
                tsk.Text2 = vbNullString
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```